# Indentation of list items not correct with IE, correct with Firefox, Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

There's something wrong with my CSS-code for a  list. Indentation of second (and further) lines of list items are not correct in IE, but okay in other browsers. See: http://jsfiddle.net/nXYee/

Any idea?

IE8 gives this result:

[image: Result in IE]

Chrome, Safari and FF give this result:

[image: Result in other browsers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This occurs because you've placed the bullet inside the list item (`list-style-position:inside;`), and the *browser* controls the space between the bullet and the `li` content, not you. Internet Explorer assigns more space between the bullet and the content than the other browsers you mentioned.

The fact that your indented content aligns correctly in Chrome/Safari/Firefox is because those browsers all implemented the same (or similar) distance between the bullet and the li content, so a `text-indent` of `1em` gives you a visually consistent result - *but really this visual consistency is just a fluke*.

(In fact, if you check closely you'll notice that Firefox is slightly out too).

If you feel it is necessary to display the bullet inside the list items, then you may find you need to use a conditional comment to feed different `text-indent` and `padding-left` values to IE (e.g. `1.5em`/`-1.5em`) - but that will break in IE10, which doesn't support conditional comments.

Personally, I would keep the bullets outside the list items, since I think you'll find it much easier to get a consistent result.

Comment: Thanks. So my CSS-code indented the first list item row to the left and so I looked as if second lines and further lined up with the first but were not. I'll change my code according also to @MMM

Comment: having the same problem, although list-style-position is already set to outside, the second and first line still don't align in IE. I'm using a list-image.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm it looks like you were overthinking a bit in terms of your css with all that list positions and negative text margin, I've simplified it to the following:

```
body {
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:1.0em;
  width:500px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type:disc;
  padding-left:1em;
  margin-left:0px;
}​
```

Tested it on IE8, looks normal.

http://jsfiddle.net/nXYee/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain it has something to do with your styles, specifically, this part:

```
li {
    list-style-position:inside;
    ...
}
ul {
    text-indent:-1em;
    padding-left:1em;
    ...
}
```

When `list-style-position` is set to `inside`, it's considered part of the list item itself and when the item wraps, it will wrap to under the item marker.  It is then indented due to your left padding being set - but it's not enough to get it to the right level. FF and Webkit may use some other algorithms to determine the position, or maybe 1em is just evaluates differently.

I have forked your jsfiddle and fixed the styles in it so that the list is now displayed correctly:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vxTw/3/

Comment: You're overwriting list-style-types in your jsfiddle and applying double paddings

Comment: double list-style-types are his original stuff, I'm not touching it.  Double padding are used once for the list itself (in 'ul'), and the other time for the text from the marker (in 'li').  Please understand the code before down-voting.

Comment: I think you're mistaken sir, in his original jsfiddle he sets it to `none` for `ul` and `disc` for `li` and you change it to `circle` for `ul` and keep `disc` for `li` (thus, that't not a valid suggestion). And I do understand the code and hence I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside !important;
}
```

fixed it I've had similar problem